# invalid number of arguments in "ssl_certificate_key" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/defaul

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, certificate

I have got my EV SSL Certificate. I am following tutorials on how to use my certificate with NGINX on Ubuntu

When I am trying to restart my nginx, I get:

```
**invalid number of arguments in "ssl_certificate_key" directive in   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

What I did so far:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default


upstream app {
# Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
server unix:/home/zhall/zoulfia/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name moneytree.space www.moneytree.space " " 178.62.19.65;
rewrite ^/(.*) https://moneytree.space/$1 permanent;
}

# HTTPS server

server {
listen 443;
server_name moneytree.space www.moneytree.space " " 178.62.19.65;
root /home/zhall/zoulfia/public;


ssl on;
ssl_certificate /home/zhall/moneytree.space.chained.crt;

**ssl_certificate_key /home/zhall/ moneytree.space.key**

ssl_session_timeout 10m;

ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

When i restart nginx with ---

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

In my log file ----

```
sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log, I get:

**invalid number of arguments in "ssl_certificate_key" directive in    /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Everything is new to me so I need your help to solve this. What am I doing wrong and most importantly how to correct this mistake?

Thank you,
Zoulfia

Answer (score 130, accepted):

It looks like you may be missing a semicolon at the end of the `ssl_certificate_key` line.

Comment: I was getting same issue in ubuntu nginx Thanks Joel C

_ssl_certificate_key path/to/certificate.crt;_

Comment: Thanks Now I on A with ssllab.com using with nginx _cat godaddy-ca.crt > godaddy-chain.crt && cat gd_bundle.crt >> godaddy-chain.crt_ 
then use in nginx.conf _ssl_certificate  /path/to/godaddy-chain.crt_

Comment: Man do I feel like a jackass ... I owe you Joel C

Comment: Cool Joel. Thanks

Comment: Damn, can't remember that I missed my ";" there. Thanks Joel !

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between "/home/zhall/" and "moneytree.space.key" and nginx see 2 arguments instead of one

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error due to an "=" in the ssl.conf file.

Correct

```
ssl_certificate_key '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/privkey.pem';
```

Not Correct

```
ssl_certificate_key =  '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/privkey.pem';
```